# where to find how g++ mangles names when compiling?

Tags: g++

where can i find informations who the g++ compiler mangle names?

e.g. i see when i have a function with two int the symbol always have the ending "ii" but is this always so? i need to get some documentation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

G++ uses the IA64 C++ ABI mangling specification.

https://itanium-cxx-abi.github.io/cxx-abi/abi.html#mangling

Comment: Dead link and Webarchive does not have it in its cache.